# Access existing private repositeries on github

Tags: git, github, repository, private

While accessing the private repository from github, I am getting an error.

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

However, I have checked my mac connection with github and that seems to be working fine and giving me

```
Hi xxx! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

on running

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

So, I have 2 questions now,

1. Can I access the private depositary created by someone else.
2. If yes, how? As I have tried HTTPS, SSH already but getting the above stated error.

Help much appreciated!!

Comment: can we assume you took Github's recommendations and checked A) you have rights to the repo, and B) the repo exists ( rule out typos )

Comment: If a repository is private, it's private. The owner of the repository would have to add you as a collaborator to let you access *his* *private* repository.

Comment: Thanks JB got it, so there is no means by how i can access that repository without access permissions grated by owner.